# Passing in API Key and Parameters with RestClient

Tags: ruby, sinatra

In my application I have a user pass in a form that fires out an API request and then displays the results of the query.

I allow the user to to select many or few parameters.  The problem I  get is a 401 Authorization error and I believe that is because the apikey isn't being recognized (there is no password, username needed for the api and no limits).

Application:

```
post '/search' do 

    phrase = params.fetch "phrase" #mandatory
    @delimiters = ""

    start_date = params.fetch "start_date"
    start_date.empty? ? start_date = "" : @delimiters << "From #{start_date},"

    end_date = params.fetch "end_date" 
    end_date.empty? ? end_date = "" : @delimiters << "To #{end_date}"

    api_result = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, url: "capitolwords.org/api/1/text.json?phrase=#{phrase}
                                         &page=0&apikey=", 
                                         headers: {params: {:start_date => start_date, 
                                         :end_date => end_date},
                                         :Authorization => ENV['SUNLIGHT_API_KEY']}, 
                                         timeout: 10)       
end
```

The delimiter is what I'm using to catch all the parameters passed in so I can show the user what they searched by.  I've read the documentation at https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client and they don't mention passing in api keys.

This is part of a refactoring process - passing in the parameters one by one as #{@parameter_example} works but makes my code less readable and I then manually must set up @parameter_example = "&parameter_example=#{parameter_example}" which seems overly verbose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the [capitalwords.org documentation](http://capitolwords.org/api/1/), it seems that the `api key` along with the `phrase`, `start_date`, `end_date` params should be passed as part of the [query string.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) So your rest-client request should look like this:

```
api_result = RestClient::Request.execute(method: :get, 
                                            url: "capitolwords.org/api/1/text.json", 
                                        headers: {params: {:phrase => phrase, 
                                                           :start_date => start_date,
                                                           :end_date => end_date,
                                                           :page => 0,
                                                           :apikey => ENV['SUNLIGHT_API_KEY']}}, 
                                        timeout: 10)
```

I think that in order to pass params like this (using headers params hash) to `RestClient::Requeest.execute` then the url you request should not include any params or else rest-client fails to produce the correct url. That's why I moved `page` and `phrase` from url into params phrase hash.

Comment: OK, I think this might be the right solution.  At the moment it doesn't recognize phrase as a parameter however.

Comment: @user3162553 You could do something like this to troubleshoot your problem, replace :url hostname with 127.0.0.1:8888 or localhost:8888 (8888 is just a random port number, use one that suits you) and on another term run something like `nc -l 8888` (nc is netcat tool). Then execute your RestClient::Request and check what request RestClient sends to netcat.

Comment: OK, I found the problem - i need to pass parameters only if not nil. It's passing the params into the url as &param=&param=  even if there's no value. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to do the following at the top of the file?

```
require 'dotenv'
Dotenv.load
```

Comment: Yes, the other API's are working great.  This is meant for refactoring purposes.